# How to program a batch process that has to coexist with Dropbox sync?

Tags: .net, windows, filesystems

I have a batch process written in .NET and runs on Windows.

The batch job does a series of file system operations in a particular folder, most of the operations are just creating copies of files, editing their contents sometimes.

That folder is also running Dropbox sync. Whenever Dropbox sync process runs and coincides with any file operation going on with my batch process, that file operation fails with Access Denied error. What would be the best way to deal with this ? Dropbox sync cant be disabled, and it has no way of being scheduled. The issue is intermittent.

The following algorithm has been tried and has failed too sometimes

```
IF CanAccessFile(path) THEN
      DoFileOperationA(path); 
END IF
```

Sometimes the code passes the `IF` check, and Dropbox takes over the access of the file Afterwards. Is there any OS level sync-lock type mechanism for a file that I  can use ?

Answer (score 0):

Checking if the file can be opened before you open it creates a race condition since, as you've pointed out, Dropbox can jump in there and do its thing after CanAccessFile, but before DoFileOperationA finishes.  Have you tried opening the file using the [Fileshare.None](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter of the [File.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725(v=vs.110).aspx) method?

If not, here's an example of how to do that, from the File.Open docs (linked above):

```
Using fs As FileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
```

See if you can modify DoFileOperationA to open the file that way, and post if that helps :)

Comment: You could also try using [FileStream.Lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Most of my operations are File.Copy(), File.Delete(), only a few have to do with Write-ing new files.

Comment: It is really weird that dropbox doesn't even let you copy files while it was syncing other files.  I don't think it locks the entire directory...  Actually, have you tried just totally denying dropbox access to the entire directory using [Directory.SetAccessControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setaccesscontrol.aspx)?  It's a pretty excessive solution but it just might work, although you'd need to be careful that you don't accidentally lock _yourself_ out of the directory too ;)